# Failure in the middle of a Debian upgrade

Tags: debian, rescue

I am facing an very serious problem. I am updating my laptop from Debian 7.0 to the current testing distro. One package(`veusz.helper`) dependency was lost and the upgrade process can't move forward. But nearly 1000 packages have been uninstalled already. And the system is stuck.

So I have to reboot, but the problem is the system has also uninstalled the `vmlinuz` and `initrd.gz` so grub cannot recognize the Linux volume. And the newly downloaded packages are still in `/var/apt/cache/archives`.

Is there any way I can proceeded with the upgrade process and figure out the dependency problem?

Comment: Rollback your backup.

Answer (score 2):

if your grub menu has other kernels available, try booting one of them.  you should be able to repair your system by repeatedly running `dpkg --configure --pending`, `apt-get -f install`, and `apt-get dist-upgrade` until there are no errors.

if not, you'll have to boot a rescue CD or USB stick.  my favourite is Clonezilla because it has both 64-bit and 32-bit versions - most others are 32-bit only which makes it impossible to chroot to a 64-bit system.

if you boot a rescue CD, you'll need to mount your laptop's root file system (e.g. as /mnt), and bind-mount /proc, /sys, and /dev under /mnt too.  if you have a separate /boot partition, you will need also to mount /boot as /mnt/boot.  then you can chroot to /mnt

e.g. if your rootfs is /dev/sda1 and your /boot is /dev/sda2 you would boot a rescue CD, get a root shell, and do something a lot like this:

```
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/boot
for i in proc dev sys dev/pts ; do mount -o bind /$i /mnt/$i ; done
chroot /mnt
```

you should now be able to repair the system as mentioned above (by repeatedly running `dpkg --configure --pending`, etc until there are no errors).

when you have finished, check that the kernel is installed and the initramfs exists, unmount the filesystems (in the reverse order that you mounted them) and reboot.

e.g.

```
exit   # exit from the chroot.
for i in dev/pts sys dev proc /boot / ; do umount /mnt/$i ; done
sync
shutdown -r now
```

the `sync` isn't really necessary.  for arcane historical reasons it just makes me feel better - it's a mystical defense against eldritch horrors like yog sothoth and sco unix.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestions.@Craig Sanders I have used the second chroot way and get all my problems solved!

Comment: you're welcome.  please accept and/or upvote the answer if it helped solve your problem.